# Upload/download file using winrm4j

Tags: java, powershell, winrm

I am using winrm4j java library and it works great to run powershell or native windows commands. But I was wondering if winrm4j can upload/download files. For instance, with powershell, we can upload a file from local computer to remote computer by running:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <remoteComputerName> -Credential $creds
Copy-Item -Path '<localFileLocation>' -Destination '<futurRemoteFileLocation>' -ToSession $session
Remove-PSSession $session
```

How can I upload/download files with winrm4j ?

Comment: To try avoid asking questions that have a "Yes" or "No" answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I found in winrm4j project test classes this class : https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j/blob/806a943a3d68f3a6ad23385375c61a53c7fbec43/winrm4j/src/test/java/io/cloudsoft/winrm4j/winrm/AbstractWinRmToolLiveTest.java#L193.

It implements a method called "copyTo", which is pretty closed of what I want to do. It seems that the devs think about adding this method to the WinRmTool class. However, the methodology used is pretty dirty, and execution time also very long. I am a little disapointed to do not find another way to accomplish this.

I was inspired by this method to make download and upload methods using winrm4j :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes;

import io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmClientContext;
import io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool;
import io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmToolResponse;

public class CWinrmTest {
    private static final Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WinRmClientContext context = WinRmClientContext.newInstance();

        WinRmTool tool = WinRmTool.Builder.builder("192.168.70.1", "User", "Password")
                .authenticationScheme(AuthSchemes.NTLM)
                .port(5985)
                .useHttps(false)
                .context(context)
                .build();

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("path/to/local/uploadFile.txt");
        uploadTo(inputStream, "path/to/remote/uploadFile.txt", tool);

        downloadFrom("path/to/remote/downloadFile.txt", "path/to/local/downloadFile.txt", tool);

        context.shutdown();
    }

    protected static void uploadTo(InputStream source, String destination, WinRmTool tool) throws IOException {
        int chunkSize = 1024;

        byte[] inputData = new byte[chunkSize];
        int bytesRead;
        int expectedFileSize = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = source.read(inputData)) > 0) {
            byte[] chunk;
            if (bytesRead == chunkSize) {
                chunk = inputData;
            } else {
                chunk = Arrays.copyOf(inputData, bytesRead);
            }
            tool.executePs("If ((!(Test-Path " + destination + ")) -or ((Get-Item '" + destination + "').length -eq " +
                    expectedFileSize + ")) {Add-Content -Encoding Byte -path " + destination +
                    " -value ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(\"" + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(chunk))
                    + "\"))}");
            expectedFileSize += bytesRead;
        }
    }

    protected static void downloadFrom(String remoteFilePath, String destination, WinRmTool tool) throws IOException {

        String cmd = "If ((Test-Path '" + remoteFilePath
                + "')) { [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('" + remoteFilePath + "'))}";
        WinRmToolResponse response = tool.executePs(cmd);

        String content64 = response.getStdOut().replace("\r\n", "");
        String content = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(content64), ENCODING);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(destination);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        try {
            bufferedWriter.write(content);
        } finally {
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```